# How do I get rid of the Executing/Progress Bar when running a Gradle application?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to build a console based application but whenver I run

```
./gradlew run
```

I get thr progress bar which looks like this:

```
<=========----> 75% EXECUTING [29s]
```

Is there anyway I can remove this bar (which hangs out until the application ends)? Or is there a better way to write console base applications with gradle?

The version is 4.3.1

Comment: did you try the gradle `console` parameter ? see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_customizing_log_format . maybe one option (plain? ) will disable this progress bar.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti There are still some artifacts being printed out, but it is a lot better. If you want to post that as answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried with `gradle.startParameter.consoleOutput = ConsoleOutput.Plain` (Gradle Kotlin) inside the Task; however, it gets ignored.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can configure the Gradle log format using `console` command line parameter, as described here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_logging

Try with : `./gradlew run --console=plain`

Answer (score 9):

Another way of doing this seems to be by setting the `TERM` environment variable to `dumb`.

Try `TERM=dumb ./gradlew run`

Answer (score 7):

To make it a **default behavior**, add `org.gradle.console=plain` to gradle.properties file (prerequisite Gradle version is more than 4.x).

For **one time execution** add `--console=plain` flag to your command.

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is specific to using the gradle wrapper, but if you're using the [Gradle Tooling API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/third_party_integration.html#embedding), you can control the color output via 
[setColorOutput](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/tooling/ConfigurableLauncher.html#setColorOutput-boolean-). Combined with the `--quiet` argument (set via [withArguments](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/tooling/ConfigurableLauncher.html#withArguments-java.lang.String...-)), this results in plain-text output.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, to change the default behavior, adding `org.gradle.console=plain` to the project's `gradle.properties` does work but only when there is no `org.gradle.console` property set in the gradle.properties file in `GRADLE_USER_HOME`. In my case, the `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/gradle.properties` file had `org.gradle.console=verbose`, which I couldn't change, and adding `org.gradle.console=plain` to the project's gradle.properties had no effect. Instead, I needed to add `systemProp.org.gradle.console=plain` to the project's gradle.properties, as gradle picks the first value it finds for a property and the first place it looks for is a system property or `-D` property, as documented [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)